# Обособление части предложения

Tags: запятые, уточнения

Друзья, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста

Само предложение:

*В адресе доставки был указан только дом без подробностей о том, куда конкретно направляться, поэтому он связался, когда был у адреса.*

Нужно ли поставить запятую перед "без подробностей"? И если да, то почему.

Вот так:

*В адресе доставки был указан только дом, без подробностей о том, куда конкретно направляться, поэтому он связался, когда был у адреса.*

Comment: *В адресе доставки был указан только номер дома, поэтому он связался с клиентом, когда оказался рядом с указанным домом*.

Comment: *был у адреса => у дома* — остальное не так критично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна, потому что без неё получается так:
*только {дом без подробностей}* || Это ерунда. Нам же нужно "только" отнести лишь к слову "дом".

Здесь обстоятельства как бы равносильны: "только" = "без подробностей".
Здесь пояснительная конструкция, потому что можно вставить "то есть". Пояснение — это обозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119